# PATH environment variable is different in the Qt C++ code and process explorer tool

Tags: c++, qt, environment-variables, dynamic-loading

I am trying to update the `PATH` environment variable inside my C++ program using Qt on Windows 10. There is something wired in this scenario that I cannot understand. The strange point is that the value of `PATH` environment variable is getting different in the C++ code and in [process explorer tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) after dynamically loading a Matlab .dll file (i.e. MatlabEngine.dll). Here is a simplified version of the code:

```cpp
    QString new_path = getNewPath();
    bool res = qputenv("PATH", new_path.toStdString().c_str()); 
    assert(res);
    auto applied_path = qgetenv("PATH"); // Line X of the code: process explorer shows the same value for PATH environment variable as applied_path variable
    
    // load a Matlab .dll dynamically
    if (!oneMatlabDll.load())
    {
       throw someException;
    }
    
    applied_path = qgetenv("PATH"); // Line Y of the code: process explorer does not show the updated value of PATH environment variable as before. But, the applied_path variable is exactly the same as line X.
```

Does anyone have any idea why the value of `PATH` environment variable retrieved by `qgetenv()` is different from the one showed by process explorer tool? Here are some thoughts:

- An issue with process explorer tool
- An issue with `qgetenv()` method
- Dynamically loading the .dll file runs some hidden code that causes this problem. (?)

**Update 1:**
If I add this silly line of code after line Y, then the process explorer shows the same value as the output of `qgetenv("PATH")`:

```
qputenv("PATH", qgetenv("PATH")); // this line fixes the issue
```

Comment: I never really got how Windows handles the environment but for what I know from *ix OSes: The environment of a process is inherited from the parent process. Changes to the environment are applied to the current process. (AFAIK, a process is not allowed to change the environment for its parent process.) Aside from this, Windows seems to extend this basic simple principle somehow and sometimes (but not in every application)...

Comment: @Scheff Yes, it was a typo. I fixed it. Thanks. Also take a look at the update of Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any reason behind this problem. It seems that it can be an internal issues comes from Qt/Windows. So, the only workaround that I have found is to add the below line again:

```
qputenv("PATH", qgetenv("PATH")); // this line fixes the issue
```